# Stop Galaxy S2 from reading homepages out loud?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, text-to-speech

My Galaxy S2 has suddenly started reading all homepages out loud, and it is really annoying. Does anyone know how to stop it?

I am running the new ICS software.

**Update**

When the computer voice is reading out loud, it seems that I can turn down the volume of that voice, which mitigates the problem for now.

Also, it seems that it is only the browser and the facebook apps for which everything is read out loud.

**Update again**

In Settings -> Applications -> Running I see a "Voice commands", and under that the Samsung TTS process is running. When I force close that one, a voice says "driving mode off". However, the process is relaunched immediately again.

Seems the suggestion about disabling driving mode is the way to go, however I cannot find any such option anywhere in the settings menu.

**Update again again**

This is getting pretty weird. I managed to disable driving mode. You can do that by going to the voice command app by double tapping the "home" button. However, that did not help, it is still reading all homepages out loud.

Any help please, it would be very much appreciated?

Comment: Can you once look at Menu -> Settings -> Accessibility

Comment: I have looked in most of the settings menu, including that one. And there is nothing that indicates that it should be reading anything out loud.

Comment: @bjarkef The TalkBack service is off?

Comment: @onik: I cannot find anything called TalkBack in the settings menu, nor any such running process. Where should I go look for TalkBack?

Comment: @bjarkef It should be among the first options under `Settings -> Accessibility` if it's available. If not, then disregard.

Comment: There is no such thing available under accessibility, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Check your settings for `Settings -> Accessibility -> Install web scripts` and make sure that it's turned off.

*For JellyBean*
Settings > Accessibility > Vision > "Enhance web accessibility" -Set to "Do not allow"
This fixed my issue, guess I should stop playing with 500 settings at one time.
Also try Settings>accessibility>Hearing>Turn off all sounds checkbox

Comment: This is the right answer, this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Car mode / Driving mode, maybe. Perhaps in ICS - it is under Android's SETTINGS > VOICE INPUT AND OUTPUT

Comment: I cannot find anything called "car mode" or "driving mode" in any of the settings menus. :/

Comment: Finally found that setting, see my updated question, it is turned off, it does not mitigate the problem. :/

Comment: I have an S2 but running Gingerbread. When Driving mode is on - incoming calls and messages are read out. There isn't any option to read the text in the browser. Is it only the default web browser that reads out the content of the page or do you have Text to Speech in other apps reading out what's on-screen as well?

Comment: Since you have ICS, open the keyboard and check the keyboard settings - i think the default ICS keyboard has a text to speech feature included also.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with text to speech on my Galaxy Tab GT-P7500. I resolved the problem by disabling Accesability under Settings on my device. The Accesabilty fuction hinders/allows application to interact with you device. So when I would like to read text and would like to listen to it read out aloud then enables Accesability. Hope this have helped.